# Can I patch the PPC 12.04 kernel to allow older ATI drivers to install?

Tags: 12.04, radeon, patch, ppc

Right now, with a PowerMac G5, the only way to install the graphics driver from the ATI binaries would be to patch the kernel, for my Radeon 9600 is only supported with the 9.3 installer, while the 12.6 has no effect. My current issue is that the new kernel with an old driver is preventing the install. Is there a way to correctly patch this without issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling is no, because the current (3.2) kernel [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) may not be fully backward-compatible with the binary blobs in the old 9.3 installer. Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick question, do you know of any graphics drivers that would work with Radeon 9600 and PPC that are open source?

Comment: Which driver is loaded by default when you first install 12.04?

Comment: It gives me: Unknown

Comment: `snackadoodlepop@snackadoodlepop-desktop:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
0000:f0:10.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV350 AP [Radeon 9600] [1002:4150]`

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of `lsmod` please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KLm1wnrr

Comment: Well, you are using the [open-source `radeon`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1076904/) driver provided by the kernel; I don't think there's another alternative that will perform better (other than binary blobs).

Comment: Thank you, for some reason Unity 3D can't work on here, and with binary blobs there's no telling what could go wrong.

Comment: Did it work in 11.10?

Comment: Unfortunately, 12.04 is the only Ubuntu version put on here, the only reason I expected it to work is that the netbook I have with Intel Integrated worked with better visual effects than here.